# vector-valued function space definition except for measure zero

Tags: measure-theory, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-measure, sobolev-spaces

I am wondering what's the correct way to mathematically describe the following problem. Say you have an object that can be defined as an open set $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^d$, where the dimension $ d=2,3$. What you normally find in scientific articles on mechanics is that the boundary of the object is obtained as $\Gamma \equiv \overline{\Omega} \setminus \Omega$ and then you can define a vector-valued function space in $\Omega$ as 
$$
  \mathcal{V} = \left\{ \left. \mathbf{v} : \mathbf{v} \left( \mathbf{x} \right) \in \mathbb{R}^d  \right| \, v_i \in H^1 \left( \Omega \right), i=1,\ldots,d  \right\},
$$
where $H^1 \left( \Omega \right)$ is the Hilbertian Sobolev space of square integrable functions (and square integrable first-order derivatives).

So far so good, but now let's say you have $n$ sets of measure zero within $\Omega$, say $\Gamma_i^c, i=1,\ldots, n$.
In my case $\Gamma_i^c$ represents a crack in the object of the body where clearly the function is not defined (the function $\mathbf{v}$ has a jump). But I can still compute the integral of $\mathbf{v}$ at both sides of the crack by properly dividing the integration regions (so the crack has measure zero).
This now confuses me as I don't know how to properly define my vector-valued function space.

Can I just simply state 
$$
  \mathcal{V} = \left\{ \left. \mathbf{v} : \mathbf{v} \left( \mathbf{x} \right) \in \mathbb{R}^d  \right| \, v_i \in H^1 \left( \Omega \setminus \cup_j \Gamma_j^c \right), i=1,\ldots,d  \right\}
$$
or this is wrong?
Or is it that in this case $\Gamma$ takes not only the outer boundary but also the internal cracks?
What's the proper way to mathematically describe the vector-valued function space for this problem?

Comment: It is true that the boundary of $\Omega \setminus \cup_j \Gamma_j^c$ includes $\cup_j \Gamma_j^c$. Why is this a problem? Since you have jump discontinuities there, you need specify conditions there to have well-defined solutions, anyway.

Comment: Hi Paul, you lost me. I don't see how $\Omega \setminus \cup_j \Gamma_j^c$ includes $\cup_j \Gamma_j^c$. For me $\Gamma = \overline \Omega \setminus \Omega$ is the external boundary (without the cracks), and thus $\Omega$ contains the cracks, doesn't it? Then $\Omega \setminus \cup_j \Gamma_j^c$ is the solid (with no cracks). Am I wrong?

Comment: Can we call $B := \cup_j \Gamma_j^c$ to make this less messy? After all, your question has nothing to do with how $B$ is built. What I said was: the *boundary* of $\Omega \setminus B$ includes $B$. This is obvious as $B$ has measure $0$ and therefore has no interior. So any point of $B$ has elements of $\Omega$ not in $B$ in each of its neighborhoods, which means that it is in $\overline{\Omega \setminus B}$. So $\Omega \setminus B$ does not contain the cracks and its boundary is $\Gamma \cup B$. So you must include $B$ in any boundary conditions.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I understand what you mean now. The problem is that I am not expecting to enforce BCs on $B$, but to use functions that have a jump in the displacement field. So I'm still confused by how to define $\mathcal{V} \left( \Omega \right)$ to do this. According to your message, this space can still be defined as $ \mathcal{V} = \left\{\mathbf{v}|v_i \in H^1\left(\Omega\right)\right\}$ because $B$ has zero measure, but I'm not sure this is strictly correct. Something's missing since I'm expecting to use functions that are discontinuous across the crack. Does this make any sense?

Comment: No, $\mathcal{V} = \left\{\mathbf{v}|v_i \in H^1\left(\Omega\setminus B\right)\right\}$. You have to place some conditions on the behavior around $B$ or else you don't get well-defined functions (i.e.,  there will be multiple solutions). The exact nature of those conditions may not be the normal BCs, but you have to have some sort of requirement there to insure uniqueness.

Comment: @PaulSinclair there's an entire research community (XFEM) that models cracks with finite element meshes that are independent of the geometry of the meshes. They don't enforce anything at the cracks, but just use functions that are discontinuous in the displacement (by adding to the finite element approximation a Heaviside function). You can even model cracks with the standard finite element method by having double nodes along the cracks, and again, you're not enforcing anything there (so I guess what's enforced is a zero traction).

Comment: Sorry, but you've missed something. They most definitely do impose conditions at those cracks. You apparently have not spotted them, but they are there.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I don't think so, and thus I ended up asking this question as I don't understand what's going on. One example: "An extended finite element method with higher-order elements for curved cracks" by Stazi et al., for the variational formulation they just say $\mathbf{u}  \in \mathcal{U}, \mathcal{U} = \left\{ \left. \mathbf{u} \right| \mathbf{u} \in C^0 \text{ except on }\Gamma_{\text {cr}}, \mathbf{u} = \bar{\mathbf{u}}  \text{ on } \Gamma_{\text u} \right\}$. You see they just say the function needs to be continuous except on the crack. Also $\delta \mathbf{v} \in \mathcal{U}_0 $.

Comment: Well, maybe they are doing something other than what I am assuming. But to give you an example, such cracks can completely disconnect $\Omega$. A triangle could be a crack. If solving an homogenous differential equation, the solution inside the triangle need not have any relation to that outside unless some additional regularity function is given.